# Optimize this very specific SQL query

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance

I need a bit of help optimizing a SQL query. Right now it takes too long and I have reached a wall with it, so I would like to know if someone knows how to modify it further. This is for SQL Server 19.

**Description of problem:**
Create a query that returns the highest concentration of occurrences within 1 hour, greater than or equal to 3, in the last 24 hours, and show the id, total number of occurrences during 24 hours, highest concentration of occurrences found within 1 hour (from the 24 hours), and time of the highest concentration.

Edit:
This is pr. id meaning that we count the occurrences and concentration for each id.

**My Solution**
The initial solution was to create CTE's to simplify the problem into sub problems.
The optimization I did was to figure out which STRAIGHT joins would provide me with the fastest results, and using a View and Index to cache the initial 24 hour rows and return the needed data instantly.

*View*

Unfortunately, it seems it is not possible to use GETDATE() when creating an index on it, as it is not a deterministic function, so help with that would also be appreciated.
For now I guess you have to manually input the date for the index to work.

```
CREATE VIEW vwOccurrences
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT id, ReceivedDateTime, COUNT_BIG(*) AS cnt
FROM TestTable
WHERE ReceivedDateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, convert(datetime, '2022-08-08 22:59:01.137', 101))
GROUP BY id, ReceivedDateTime ;
```

*Index*

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_vwOccurrences_id_ReceivedDateTime ON vwOccurrences (id, ReceivedDateTime);
```

*Query*

```
WITH totals AS (
    SELECT id, SUM(cnt) AS total_cnt
    FROM vwOccurrences
    GROUP BY id
),
concentrations AS (
    SELECT o1.id, o1.ReceivedDateTime, SUM(o2.cnt) AS concentration
    FROM vwOccurrences o1
    LEFT JOIN vwOccurrences o2
        ON o1.id = o2.id
        AND o2.ReceivedDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, o1.ReceivedDateTime) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, o1.ReceivedDateTime)
    GROUP BY o1.id, o1.ReceivedDateTime
),
max_concentrations AS (
    SELECT id, MAX(concentration) AS max_concentration
    FROM concentrations
    GROUP BY id
),
max_concentration_ReceivedDateTime AS (
    SELECT c.id, c.ReceivedDateTime
    FROM concentrations c
    RIGHT JOIN max_concentrations m ON c.id = m.id AND c.concentration = m.max_concentration
),
final_result AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT o.id, t.total_cnt, m.max_concentration, mct.ReceivedDateTime
    FROM vwOccurrences o
    LEFT JOIN totals t ON o.id = t.id
    INNER JOIN max_concentrations m ON o.id = m.id AND m.max_concentration >= 3
    INNER JOIN max_concentration_ReceivedDateTime mct ON m.id = mct.id 
)
SELECT id, total_cnt, max_concentration, ReceivedDateTime
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY max_concentration ASC) AS rn
    FROM final_result
) AS subquery
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

*Generating DB data*

Script to generate data in database:
Note: (A usual database will have between 2-3000 occurrences total in the 24 hour span).
It is slower the fewer id's there are, as the heavy comparison happens with the concentrations pr. id.

```
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    'SERVER=127.0.0.1;'
    'DATABASE=TestDB;'
)

# Create a cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Insert values into the table
id = "123456"


# Get current date
current_date = datetime.now()

# Prepare the SQL query
query = '''
    INSERT INTO TestTable (id, ReceivedDateTime)
    VALUES (?, ?)
'''

# Execute the query
for i in range(1, 300):
    cursor.execute(query, (id, current_date+ + timedelta(seconds=i)))

# Commit the transaction
conn.commit()

# Close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question and tag the database you are using ?

Comment: @SelVazi Unfortunately it is not data that is available to the public. But I will add an sql script that can generate a lot of data quickly.

Comment: The problem description is ambiguous. The clock shows 09:20. To look at the last 24 hours means that I look for all rows > yesterday 09:20. Yes? And now I want to find the hour (i.e. the sixty minutes?) with most rows in it. That can be yesterday 17:46 to 18:46 for instance. Yes? If this hour has less than three rows, then I dismiss the result. If two or more hours have the same maximum row count, I show all these hours. These may be 17:46-18:46, 17:47-18:47, 17:48-18:48 for instance. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are almost correct. You should not show tmore than the hour interval with the highest concentration. So in your example, if the highest concentration happened at 17:47-18:47, you only show the concentration at that interval. If there are more instances with the same concentration, take the first instance.

Comment: Okay. And this is SQL Server? Or some other DBMS?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Correct, I will add that to the top.

Comment: Hi. At this site it is important to use a "tag" that identifies the relevant dbms e.g. if you hover over the "sql" tag you can  read this: *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead*. Inside your question we can see `DRIVER={SQL Server}` so use that tag instead of "sql". (& I just did that.)

Comment: Use a temp table or two to split that massive query up. CTEs don't typically help performance.

Comment: @DaleK The main problem arises with the joins in the final_result CTE, so I don't think it would provide more benefit than being more readable. Also I don't think we are allowed to create a new table.

Comment: On the contrary, if you put your cte results from the fast version into a temp table, then add your joins, it will almost certainly be faster. Complex ctes can result in very complex execution plans, because it's a single execution plan. Whereas splitting it into multiple, simpler plans can often be faster.

Comment: @DaleK Ah ok, thanks for that bit of info. I will definitely think of applying this.

Comment: It looks like you can massively improve this with window functions. When you say "concentration of occurrences within 1 hour", do you mean to say that you want to look at each whole hour individually (say 9:45-10:45 and 10:45-11:45) or do ou want to work backwards 1 hour for each row (so all occurrences before a 10:55 row, and all occurrences before a 11:27 row, separately working back a whole hour from each)? The former can be done purely with window functions, the latter is much more difficult and requires a join. Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: @Charlieface I will look into the window functions, thanks for the tip. And I am sorry that I cannot provide sample data.
The basic idea for this is that there are some "objects" that we want to track, and if they go haywire, they will produce a lot of noise in the database. So we want to check if that object is faulty by checking its "concentration" in a 1 hour span, in the last 24 hours.
There can be a lot of objects with other "ids".
It is a bit edge casey to check that many, but it does happen rarely and I dont want to break our customers servers with that query.

Comment: OK but what I want to know is how are you working out this 1 hour span? Are you splitting up each 24hr block into 1hr blocks, or are you working backwards and forwards half hour from each individual row?

Answer (score 0):

Below, I am trying to get to a reasonable query. Then I am thinking about the appropriate indexes or other means to speed up the query.

In 24 hours there are infintely overlapping hours. If we looked at minutes only, there'd be 1381 of them, if I am not mistaken (e.g. looking at one day from 00:00 to 23:59, we'd get 00:00-00:59, 00:01-01:00, 00:02-01:01, ..., 23:00-23:59). With datetimes we even look at microseconds, i.e. millions of overlapping hours.

In order to reduce this, we must look at the datetimes that exist in the table. If we run the query at midnight and only have the four datetimes 00:30, 00:45, 23:30 and 23:45 in the last 24 hours, then there are four hours we must look at: 00:30-01:29, 00:45-01:44, 23:30-00:29, 23:45-00:44, where those last two "hours" are actually just parts of an hour, because it is not 00:29 or 00:44 yet. We could even dismiss the last range, as 23:45-00:00 is covered by 23:30-00:00, but I won't build in extra logic for this.

In case of ties, you want to pick one result row, so this becomes a TOP(1) query. This is what I've come up with:

```
WITH hours AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    receiveddatetime AS start_dt, -- inclusive
    DATEADD(HOUR, 24, receiveddatetime) AS end_dt -- exclusive
  FROM testtable
  WHERE receiveddatetime >= DATEADD(HOUR, 24, GETDATE())
)
SELECT TOP (1)
  hours.start_dt,
  hours.end_dt,
  cnt.total
FROM hours
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM testtable t
  WHERE t.receiveddatetime >= hours.start_dt
    AND t.receiveddatetime < hours.end_dt
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) cnt
ORDER BY cnt.total DESC;
```

If there can't be two rows with the same receiveddatetime (because of a unique constraint), you can of course remove `DISTINCT` from the query.

Now, how do we access rows in the testtable? In both parts, the determination of the hours and the counting, we only look at the receiveddatetime. This means that an index on that column should be what is needed.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON testtable (receiveddatetime);
```

If this doesn't suffice, you may consider partitioning your table by receiveddatetime somehow, so you don't have to work with the whole table, but only few partitions. I don't know what table partition criteria SQL Server features and what kind of partinioning would best here in SQL Server, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.
I will try to apply some of this to my solution :)